# Calling an Event or Method on a View from a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to use the Transitionals library to create a slide show, but I am having problems working with the TransitionNext() method. This is what I have on my SelectorControl.xaml.

```
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="400" Width="600">

      <controls:Slideshow x:Name="MainSlideshow">

            <controls:SlideshowItem Background="Blue">
                <jamesTest:PlayerDisplay DataContext="{Binding CurrentPlayer}" />
            </controls:SlideshowItem>

            <controls:SlideshowItem >
                <jamesTest:PlayerDisplay DataContext="{Binding SelectedPlayer}" />
            </controls:SlideshowItem>

    </Grid>

    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="StartStopButton" Content="Stop!" Background="Black" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"                         
           Command="{Binding StartButtonCommand}"
           Visibility="{Binding BeginSlideShow, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>


    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainSlideshow.TransitionNext();
    }
```

As you can see the Button has both a Click event and a command that the ViewModel responds to. My question is, how do I simply call "TransitionNext()" while I'm on the ViewModel?

I've been playing around with Interactions/Triggers, but it seems to be geared more the other way... I'm a little stuck. The below code lets me call back to the ViewModel when "TranisitionNext" is called, but not the other way round.

```
            <interact:Interaction.Triggers>
                <interact:EventTrigger EventName="TransitionNext">
                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ViewModelMethod"></ei:CallMethodAction>
                </interact:EventTrigger>
            </interact:Interaction.Triggers>
```

So it all works - I just want to be able to invole TransitionNext from the ViewModel and not have to do it in the View. Can anyone help?

Comment: i never face this issue because most of the time my commands usually calls a method inside my ViewModel, maybe consider going this rout?

Comment: The thing is, I need to invoke a method on the control I'm working with (Slideshow.TransitionNext()), and I don't know how to do this in the ViewModel.

Comment: so basically  `Slideshow.TransitionNext()` is a `VIEW` related method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `MainSlideshow` object is a view object, you cannot call its methods from the viewmodel directly. Remember that in MVVM pattern, a viewmodel must not have any direct references to its view. So, you have to call the `Slideshow.TransitionNext()` method from your view.

You can do this, for example, using a [DataEventTrigger](https://expressionblend.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Common/Interactivity/DataEventTrigger.cs) from Expression Blend Samples.

```
<controls:Slideshow x:Name="MainSlideshow">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <samples:DataEventTrigger EventName="ViewModelEvent">
            <local:TransitionNextAction/>
        </samples:DataEventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</controls:Slideshow>
```

`TransitionNextAction` is your custom action in this case:

```
class TransitionNextAction: TriggerAction<Slideshow>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object o)
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.TransitionNext();
    }
}
```